# Select within the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm studying SQL statements and i got stucked in this scenario.

The problem is to select data that has associantion column with another in the same table, the result that i want is to select " Name of employe", "Reports to" , "The name of your boss" (selecting the name associating with the employeId)

[image: [1]: https://pasteboard.co/IcqUYbB.png "execution of queries"]

I've tried selecting in tha same querie the columns associating them, but didn't work.

```
/*1*/
SELECT employeeNumber,firstName, (select firstname  from employees where reportsTo = employeeNumber) as boss from employees;

/*2*/
SELECT e.firstName ,'Reports to' as 'Report', (SELECT e2.firstName from employees e2 where e.employeeNumber = e2.reportsTo) AS Boss  
from employees e;
```

Both failed

I'm getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE `LEFT` SELF JOIN to also include the Main Boss

```
select 
lower.employeeNumber
,lower.firstName
,higher.firstName as boss
from employees lower
left outer join employees higher
   on higher.employeenumber = lower.reportsto
```

Comment: Yeah, this works! thank you, i will read this code and understand the magic that left outer join did

Answer (score 0):

you need to learn join concept and a particular case where you can join a table to itself like this:

```
select 
 e1.employeeNumber
,e1.firstName
,e2.firstName as boss
from employees e1
join employees e2
on e1.reportsTo=e2.employeeNumber
```

Comment: use `left`  this won't include the main boss

Comment: @maSTAShuFu you're right but I wanted to keep it simple

Answer (score 0):

Use a `self-join`

```
SELECT e1.employeeNumber,e1.firstName, 
       e2.firstname as boss 
  FROM employees e1
  LEFT JOIN employees e2 
    ON e1.reportsTo = e2.employeeNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do a join of the table with itself (you dont need to use an alias in both tables but i think it avoids confusion)

```
Select a.employeeNumber,a.firstName, b.firstNameAs 'Boss' FROM employees As 'a' JOIN employees As 'b'  WHERE a.reportsTo = b.employeeNumber
```